# Terrain tool baking light unity HDRP UV problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-terrain

I'm trying to bake my lights, but my terrain isn't displaying the baking as it should. The baking is working well, as you can see on my lightmap, but the terrain is displaying the entire map instead of just the part where it's baked. Is there any solution to say to avoid this "UV problem" when I try to bake my lights ?

I'm on Unity 2021.3.10f1 and I tried 2021.3.20f1 where I got the same problem

I'm using HDRP

My baked lightmaps and the result on the lightmap view

[image: 1]

I tried changing version and I have no idea where to go with that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :
The problem is that Unity's lightmap preview does not handle non-square terrains and UV tiling well. If you have this kind of problem, it will not affect the lights in the shaded view. If you want to avoid this problem, only create square terrains.